# Cannot Load Dhango Fixtures into database

Tags: django, django-fixtures

I am able to load 1 fixture file into the database, but not the 2nd file.  I run the command python manage.py loaddata fixture.json, and I get the error.  I'm not sure how to solve this serialization error, any insights appreciated.

The error:

```
    for obj in objects:
  File "/Users/ayunas/.local/share/virtualenvs/CS24-BW-MUD-lJVJyZQx/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/json.py", line 73, in Deserializer
    raise DeserializationError() from exc
django.core.serializers.base.DeserializationError: Problem installing fixture '/Users/ayunas/Documents/lambda/CS24-BW-MUD/tower_app/fixtures/test_fixture.json':
```

Here is how the fixture file looks like:

```
[
    {
      "model": "tower_app.item",
      "pk": 1,
      "fields": {
        "item_name": "Black Stone",
        "description": "a white stone from Paradise, blackened by the sins of mankind.",
        "strength": 10,
        "item_type": "weapon",
        "playerID" : null,
        "roomID" : 4
      }
    }
]
```

Comment: Is it missing the closing square bracket? And does it have an unneeded comma after the last curly bracket?

Comment: @jcfollower, the syntax of the json object is correct.  I updated it above

Comment: Could the issue be that you've hardcoded the pk to 1?

Comment: No, because I have another fixture file where the pk is hard coded, and it works just fine.  Here's a snippet from the other fixture json file that loads properly:
```[
  {
    "model": "tower_app.room",
    "pk": 12,
    "fields": {
      "id": 12,
      "room_name": "Inclement'",
      "description": "Description for the Inclement' room ",
      "up": "Optimism'",
      "down": "",
      "left": "",
      "right": "Oakwood'",
      "floor": 2
    }
  }]```